# Wrong with my nginx rewrite rule

Tags: nginx

My first rewrite rule is :

```
    location / {
        root   E://w/q/__t/q/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

then I request `127.0.0.1/test.js`

I can fetch the `test.js` file in the fold `E://w/q/__t/q/`

then I update the rewrite rule, I add a `/js/` path both in my `location` and request path:

```
    location /js/ {
        root   E://w/q/__t/q/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

then I request `127.0.0.1/js/test.js`

but the nginx return `404`

So what's wrong with my code? How can make it correct?

My nginx version is 1.5.8 and my OS is Windows 7

Comment: I changed the tags because there's neither JavaScript nor Apache in this question.

Comment: Does the old url still work ? Did you reload the configuration (`nginx -s reload`) ?

Comment: @dystroy: I'm sure I have reload

Answer (score 0):

well, you don't actually use the rewrite command!

With this config, Nginx will look at E://w/q/__t/q/**js**/test.js when you request 127.0.0.1/js/test.js

So copy your js there, or use a rewrite command to remove the js part in your url.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't update the `root`, you can either do that or use `alias` instead of root

```
location /js/ {
    root   E://w/q/__t/q/js;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

or

```
location /js/ {
    alias   E://w/q/__t/q/;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

Ps: try to avoid placing [`index`](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Multiple_Index_Directives) and [`root`](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Root_inside_Location_Block) inside locations, it's a bad practice, also if you're going to use [`alias`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias) make sure not to use `try_files` with it